# How do I change the size of the status bar?

Tags: unity, launcher

Since Unity is going to be the default on 11.04, I'm trying it out at work where I have a 30" display. How do I make the status bar larger?

Comment: What do you mean by "status bar"?

Comment: On a 30" display, you might also be interested in changing the font resolution to something appropriate (System, Settings, Appearance, Fonts, Details, Resolution). 101 dpi is the real physical resolution of a 30 inch display. It is advisable that the resolution be divisible by 12 (for boring technical reasons).

Comment: @stefano: Good point, but doesn't the actual dpi depend on the screen resolution?

Comment: Absolutely, I'm of course assuming your resolution is 2560×1600 pixels.

Comment: By status bar you mean the height of whole upper bar or only the width of the system tray where application icons apear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a weakness in the current implementation of Unity. We will make the sizing of the panel more dynamic in 11.04. You may not be able to size it precisely but it will respond to general font size scaling preferences in a way that it doesn't today.

Comment: bump. What's the story?

Comment: As of 14.04 this option has been added under System Settings > Screen Display. Hooray!